# Automatic email send out upon registration via Sales Force

Tags: html, salesforce

I am running a campaign via Salesforce and when users register on my site it exports their info to salesforce. I also wanted there to be an automatic email that gets sent out by salesforce thanking them for registering. I don't want to have to use mailchimp because I believe it is available to do on salesforce.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow to send an email and trigger it with something that changes on the Contact when they are updated/imported from your website:  https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_workflow_cheatsheet.pdf